# Where to store persistent (until reboot) data in memory?

Tags: android

Currently, I'm storing data in a static property on my `Application` class. When the app is closed, the data remains, but when the app is then cleared from the recents menu (or the cached process is killed), the `Application` class appears to be wiped from memory as well.

I need the data to be easily accessible from activities/fragments, as well as a `BroadcastReceiver`. The data is first loaded when the `MainActivity` is launched. You can see my code at [my GitHub project](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/tree/master/android).

**Update**

I am using SQLite for storing the data, and the activity loads the data into memory when it's started. I don't think I can do this from the `BroadcastReceiver`, though, since they're limited-lifespan and SQLite is potentially long-running. The main issue is I need my `BroadcastReceiver` to be able to manipulate the same data as the activity does.

Comment: persistent until reboot isn't really persistent, is it ?

Comment: You don't.  If you need something to last longer than Application, then you need to write it to disk.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use android [preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Other ways include saving to file to disk or in a SQLite db, you can start from reading this: [saving data in android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html).

An example from the android tutorial:

```
//Saving the data
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();

//Loading of the saved data
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

You could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your SQLlite operations.

Comment: I'm already using SQLite for storing/retrieving the data in the activity, but if the data isn't already loaded, the `BroadcastReceiver` can't load it itself and modify it since SQLite is potentially long-running, can it?

Comment: You could use an Asynctask for the sql-lite operations

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting possibility is to store data as xml file. You can use for it e.g Simple XML library: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Firstly you should make annotations in a model class,

```
@Root
public class Example {

@Element
private String text;

@Attribute
private int index;

public Example() {
  super();
}  

public Example(String text, int index) {
  this.text = text;
  this.index = index;
}

public String getMessage() {
  return text;
}

public int getId() {
  return index;
}
}
```

Then you can save these objects:

```
 Serializer serializer = new Persister();
 Example example = new Example("Example message", 123);
 File result = new File("example.xml");

 serializer.write(example, result);
```

To get this file again this should do the work:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
File source = new File("example.xml");

Example example = serializer.read(Example.class, source);
```

It is one of simplest examples taken from project site, but it is possible to write nested objects as well as lists .
It is also very well documented

Comment: Although this is definitely possible, I'm already using SQLite for storing/retrieving the data in the activity. Additionally, the `BroadcastReceiver` can't do anything potentially long-running, can it?